# Using cmbright only as a math font

Tags: beamer, fonts

I would like to use cmbright package for my presentation, but only as the math font, keeping original beamer font for text.  Is this possible to do?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{isomath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
I want nice slanted $\Phi$.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `cmbright` package changes to another font by redefining `\sfdefault` and `\ttdefault`.   Just restore the defaults after loading `cmbright`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{cmss}
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{cmtt}
\usepackage{isomath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
I want nice slanted $\Phi$.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]