# How to use CMU Bright as math font?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, math-fonts

I was using `cmbright` for my thesis, but it had some problems with characters like "é", "ã" and "ł". So I changed the main font to Roboto Light, but I still want to use CMU Bright as math font. But if I try to use both fonts, cmbright end up overlapping with Roboto as the main font.

How to setup to CMU Bright not overlap Roboto? Or even a suggestion of a math font similar to CMU Bright that does not overlap with Roboto?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[sfdefault, light]{roboto}

\usepackage{cmbright}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation*}
  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\cos( x ) x^{2} + x^{e^{x+1}}} dx.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Searching more, I find the following [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382967/using-cmbright-only-as-a-math-font). So, answering my question, you just need to load `cmbright`, redefine `sfdefault` and `ttdefault`, and then load roboto.

Comment: If switching to OpenType fonts is a choice for you, have a look at NewComputerModern. It has a mesmerizing range of character-support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the loading order and redeclare the operator font to use Roboto. I'd also scale Roboto so as to match the height of CMBright.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no longer needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light,scale=0.8868]{roboto}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{\familydefault}{l}{n}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation*}
  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\cos( x ) x^{2} + x^{e^{x+1}}} dx.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]